# Getting the error 'does not name type' while programming a custom class for an Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

After programming a new library for a Arduino, the compiler does not recognize this new class and returns the error,

> BinaryCounter:15: error: 'Binary' does not name a type

Here are the files that produce the error. The class is defined in `Binary.h`, implemented in `Binary.cpp` and used in `BinaryCounter.ino`

Binary.h

```
#ifndef Binary_h
#define Binary_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Binary {
  public:
    Binary (int pins[], int numPins);
    void display(int number);
    void clear();
  private:
    boolean *_values;
    int *_pins;
    int _numPins;
    void _update();
    void _setValues (int num);
};

#endif
```

Binary.cpp

```
#include "Binary.h"

Binary::Binary(int pins[], int numPins) {
  _values = new boolean[numPins];
  _pins = pins;
  _numPins = numPins;

  for (int i = 0; i < _numPins; i ++) {
    pinMode(_pins[i], OUTPUT);
    _values[i] = false;
  }

  _update();
}

void Binary::_update() {
  for (int i = 0; i < _numPins; i ++) {
    if (_values[i]) {
      digitalWrite(_pins[i], HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(_pins[i], LOW);
    }
  }
}

void Binary::_setValues (int num) {
  for (int i = 0; i < _numPins; i ++, num/=2) {
    _values[i] = ((num%2)==1);
  }
}

void Binary::display (int number) {
  _setValues(number);
  _update();
}

void Binary::clear() {
  display(0);
}
```

and BinaryCounter.ino

```
#include <Binary.h>

int pins[] = {2,3,4,5,6};
int numPins = 5;

Binary dis(pins, numPins);

void setup() {
}

void loop() {  
  int loopEnd = 1<<numPins;
  for (int i = 0; i < loopEnd; i ++) {
    dis.display(i);
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try removing `public` from `public class Binary`

Comment: Oops, That wasn't in the actual code but a misplaced fix. I'll edit that out

Answer (score 5):

Change `<Binary.h>` to quotes `"Binary.h"` in the file BinaryCounter.

Comment: The file `Binary.h` and `Binary.cpp` are both inside a library folder that the arduino IDE includes within it's include path. Adding the files into the folder and doing the provided changes does not remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are the .cpp and .h in libraries/BinaryCounter/ directory?
Did you created the keywords.txt file?